# Chrome downloaded a file without asking

Tags: google-chrome, download, html5

I just went to a legitimate website which I visit regularly and assume is well-run and secure, and when a page on the website loaded, my browser downloaded a file called `fallback.html` without prompting. I deleted the file from the Downloads folder straight away - I'm on a work computer and my Windows policy prevents on-demand scanning.

The browser is Chrome 43.0.2357.130 m running on Windows 8.1 Pro 64 Bit.

I've done a bit of research and it seems to be something to do with HTML5 video, but I'm still surprised that the browser actually downloaded a file without asking me.

Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: What was the website - I can give it a try on my machine and see what happens.  It sounds like it has just downloaded a copy of the page you're looking at.

Comment: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/06/25/pirate_mp_pranks_telegraph/?page=2

Comment: I don't experience this at all..

Comment: I'm the same, I don't get this issue at all; I am on the same Chrome version, using Windows 7 Pro.
Whenever I have had this issue, it's usually been because I haven't configured my web server correctly, however being this is El Reg, I can't see that being the case.
Does it happen in any other browser on your machine?

Comment: AFAIK, Chome asks before downloading potentially dangerous filetypes. HTML files aren't dangerous (well, not any more dangerous than regular web pages, which are just HTML files anyway).

Comment: did it download the file to your downloads folder or did you just see that it was downloading in the bottom left corner of the screen?